# Crypto-JS hash functions return object

Tags: javascript, typescript, cryptojs

I'm trying to hash a string using the crypto-js library in a react/typescript project. I'm using crypto-js 3.1.9 and @types/crypto-js 3.1.33.

Here's some code:

```
import CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

export const hashString= (str: string): string => {
  const hash = CryptoJS.MD5(str);
  return hash;
}
```

I expect `hash` to be of type string, as specified in the documentation of the crypto-js implementation. But the function returns an object, that contains a wordarray.

I also tried calling

```
hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
```

but that didn't work, because typescript also assumes that `hash` will be a string. So a parameterized `toString` function is not allowed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)` should be correct, but you can also try `hash.toString()`

Comment: Did you solved it by adding toString() or else ways?

Comment: @NeriusJok I was never able to solve it and implemented by own MD5

Comment: `hash.toString()` is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I had this question recently and in case someone is looking for an answer, I just cast the result to a string. Seems to work fine for me.

```js
console.log(typeof CryptoJS.MD5('hello'));
console.log("String() => ", String(CryptoJS.MD5('hello')));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```